# Strange IO stream redirection events

Tags: powershell, io-redirection, redirectstandardoutput

I am using the DISM.exe (Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool) to re-image machines. My boss has asked me to create a better looking UI for this utility. My plan to do this was to re-direct the output of DISM, parse the "progress bar" that dism shows so that I can extract the percentage complete and then covert it to a float for use in my own UI.

This all seemed like it was going well until I started testing. THe DISM output looks something like this:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.2.9200.16384

Applying Image
[=================          36.7%                     ]
```

However, my powershell script was not extracting the 36.7 as it should so to further debug I took out all the parsing code so that all my code did was simply re-direct the output directly to the screen as-is.

When I did this and re-ran dism, the output looked similar except now there was no progress bar at all.

So basically, it appears that the progress bar part of the dism.exe does not use a standard print method to echo it to the screen since my script is not seeing the progress bar in the StreamReader.ReadLine() call that I am using to get the output.

Does anyone know why this would be and how I can change my script so it successfully reads the progress bar as well?

Here is the source code:

```
write-host "Initializing dism process..."
$processInfo = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

$processInfo.FileName = "dism.exe"
$processInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$processInfo.Arguments = "/Apply-Image /ImageFile:C:\images\Win864_SL-IN-837.wim /ApplyDir:D:\ /Index:1"

$process = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $processInfo

write-host "Starting up dism..."
$process.Start();

$stream = $process.StandardOutput
$str = ""

if($stream -ne $null){

    write-host "Found output stream..."

    while($str -ne $null)
    {
        $str = $stream.ReadLine()     
        write-host $str

    }
}


write-host "Stopping interception..."
```